# Group by month in a Pandas dataframe when there is no year in the datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataset with a date_time field (object) that is in this format: 01/01 01:00:00   (month/day  hour:minute:second). There is no year. I want to be able to group the dataset by month in a Pandas dataframe.

Whatever I try, I either get an error like, "Error parsing datetime string " 01/01  01:00:00" at position 3" or an out-of-bounds error. I'm a bit of a newbie here. I suspect it is a datetime formatting issue because there is no year...but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can you convert the column to a string, then prepend the year to the column?

Comment: Is it all the same year or do you need to increment year going from 12/31 to 1/1 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a year, you don't really have a date. But you can still group by month, just treat it like a string!

Something along the lines of this should work:

```py
# create a month string column, called month_str 
# the lambda function just turns the col with the yearless 'dates' into a str 
#    and takes only the first two characters
df['month_str'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[0:2])
df.groupby('month_str')
```

Comment: Or: `df.groupby(df['date_time'].str[:2])`

Comment: `get_monthly["Month"] = get_monthly["Date_Time"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[0:3])`

This worked! thanks for the suggestions.